# Using regex in javascript to match a string of words and numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I'm trying to use regex in javascript to match something, but it's not working properly. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var skipForNow = "one(1),two(2)"
var one = "one";
var tempArray = skipForNow.match(new RegExp(one+"([1-9]+)", 'g'));

document.write(tempArray[0]);
```

**Expected Output:**

one(1)

**Actual Output:**

```
JavaScript error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
```

Comment: `(` and `)` create *groups*. If you want literal parentheses characters, you need to escape them first, with backslashes.

Comment: this is the answaer skipForNow.match(new RegExp(one + "[\(]" + "[1-9]" + "[\)]", 'g'));